# Inheriting from UINavigationController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class that extends `UINavigationController`.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    var reservationId: Int
    var blankViewController: BlankViewController

    init(clientId aClientId: Int, reservationId aReservationId: Int) {

        blankViewController = BlankViewController()

        clientId = aClientId
        reservationId = aReservationId

        super.init(rootViewController: blankViewController)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This is doing things by the book. My designated initializer is calling super class designated initializer. But the app crashes at run time with this message:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 
'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'MyiOSApp.MyNavigationController'
```

Through trial and error I made the problem go away by doing this instead.

```
init(clientId aClientId: Int, reservationId aReservationId: Int) {

    blankViewController = BlankViewController()

    clientId = aClientId
    reservationId = aReservationId

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

But `init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` is not a designated initializer of the immediate super class. Technically this should not even compile. So I am super confused. What specific rule was I violating with the first code? And if indeed I was breaking some rule why did the compiler not catch if it?

One potential explanation is that `init(nibName:, bundle:)` is a required initializer. But that explanation has problems. From what I can see `init(nibName:, bundle:)`, `init(rootViewController:)` and `init?(coder:)` are **not** marked as required in the documentation or the source code view in Xcode. For some reason the compiler thinks that `init?(coder:)` is required but not so for the other init methods. All of this is very strange.

Edit: many of you are posting answers saying how to get this to work. My question is not about that. I can already get this to work as I have noted as much in my question. My question is about Swift initializer rules, and what I may be violating.

Comment: @Paulw11 the crash was not in ``init(coder)``. Please see the crash error message. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't implement the other required initialiser - init(nibName, bundle) - this is required by [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init)

Answer (score 2):

Your subclass will work if you override `init(nibName:,bundle:)` as well.

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

You will also have to provide default values for your properties.

Comment: My question was not about how to somehow get this to work. It was about Swift initializer rules and what specific rule I may have been breaking. ``init(nibName:, bundle:)`` is not marked as required. The compiler doesn't think so either. So why do I have to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize any controller from storyboard it is required to implement

`required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}`

and when you intialize controller manually allocating and intialize, you have to tell name of nib file name along with bundle name. for ref.

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)   {
        print("init nibName style")
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
```

This is good practice to have this init method

```
convenience init() {
    self.init()
}
```

Comment: ``init(nibName:, bundle:)`` is not marked as required. The compiler doesn't think so either.